# Errors are interfering with me running my code

Tags: java, visual-studio

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r19Rb.png)I am trying to learn the basics of Java and am creating a conditional command. I want to create a script that will give me a return of hello or goodbye depending on the name input. Here below is my script, I try to run it in the terminal on VS although I get a whole heap of bugs and errors, when I fix these errors I notice it makes the script incomplete. What do I need to fix here or am I just running the program wrong?

```
public class HelloGoodbye {
    
}
private static String printName(String name, int number) {
    return "my name is" + name

    if (name.equals("Kevin")) {
        System.out.println("Hello Kevin, Goodbye Kevin");
    }
    else if (name.equals(James)) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye Kevin, Hello james");
    }
}
```

Comment: Four things.  Your `return` statement should have a semicolon.  Once you have a `return` inside a method, there can't be any more lines of code afterwards (unless it's in a conditional block, in which case you can more lines after the end of the block).  `James` needs to be in `" "` marks.  And your method needs to be _inside_ your class, not outside - that is, before the final `}` of the class.

Comment: In addition to @DawoodibnKareem 5) Use an IDE so that these errors will be highlighted for you.

Comment: Wombat - it looks from the attached image like there is an IDE in play.  Nicolai is just having trouble interpreting what the errors actually mean.

Answer (score -1):

you have to return on the first line in the function, after return, the function won't be executed.

you should return the function when you are done with the function , and if you only want to return the string you should make the function like this :

```
private static void printName(String name, int number) {

    String newName = name;
    if (newName .equals("Kevin")) {
        System.out.println("Hello Kevin, Goodbye Kevin");
    }
    else if (newName.equals(James)) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye Kevin, Hello james");
    }

}
```